# Holding period determined by closing date?

Tags: united-states, stocks, capital-gains-tax, long-term

I own a stock (purchased on June 3, 2019) that I plan to sell once it becomes a long-term holding. I expected that to happen tomorrow (June 3, 2020) or later, so I was surprised when I looked at my position in Fidelity account this morning and saw that it is already listed as having a long holding period.

Is this because even if I were to sell it today, the sale wouldn't actually close until June 3 or later?

Update: Or on second thought, is it just because this is a leap year and I forgot to take February 29th into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fidelity LTCG label doesn't make sense.  The holding period for a long term  capital gain is a year and a day.  Furthermore, if the holding period spans February 29, it adds an extra day to the holding period.

Comment: Hm. On a side note, it seems ridiculous that the holding period changes when a leap year is involved, rather than being defined as a fixed number of days.

Comment: @chepner I imagine it's to abstract away the leap day. If you purchase a security on October 15, you know it'll be considered long term after October 15 the following year without having to worry about whether there's a leap year involved.

Comment: @chepner - It's not  ridiculous when you consider that every 4 years, a year has a different length.  Whether you think it's fair that the holding period is an extra day every 4 years is another story.  glibdud's abstraction is an effective and easy way to deal with it.

Comment: Defining a long-term asset as one held for 365 days would be simpler and explicit. I haven't found any explicit definition for "year" in Title 26.

Comment: I've seen the tax treatment of a leap year referenced at tax sites.  Some reputable ones are Fairmark and Greentradertax.  You might take a look there to see what's available.

Comment: I'm more interested in the law itself than in various second-hand accounts or interpretations of it.

Comment: If multiple web sites including the premier investment taxation web sites Fairmark and GreenTraderTax (which cite the law) state that it's an extra day for a cap gain holding period when there's a leap year then you don't have be a rocket scientist to conclude that it's true.  IRS Publication 523 (Selling Your Home) states that you use 366 days for a leap year (rather than 365) when Reporting Deductions Related to Your Home Sale.  Do you think that in a leap year  the IRS would use 366 days for real estate and 365 days for securities?

Comment: No, I think it should be 365 days, period, for all assets. It does not require "rocket-scientist" levels of intelligence to manage that. I don't think it's unreasonable to expect a law to be clear without 3rd party interpretation.

Comment: You're in for a long line of disappointments if you expect the tax code to be reasonable.

Comment: @glibdud From what I've read, that isn't correct always. For example, if you purchase on Feb 28 prior to a leap year, you can't sell for long term gains on Feb 29 of the leap year, you have to hold until Mar 01. Basically this rule is a fucked up design, I think we can all agree on that